# Maven Failed to Find dependency

Tags: java, spring, web-services, maven

I am using Maven Version 3.1.1.  And I am trying to compile with dependency springs-ws.  I see that this should exist in Maven via the following sites:
[Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws/2.1.4.RELEASE)
[Maven Search](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.ws%7Cspring-ws%7C2.1.4.RELEASE%7Cpom)

Here is the Stack Trace from a "mvn compile -e":

```
>mvn compile -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.233s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 10 13:44:36 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Test: Could not resolve depe
ndencies for project Test:Test:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find org.spri
ngframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven
2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until t
he update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
n project Test: Could not resolve dependencies for project Test:Co
rrectAddress:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.1
.4.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local reposi
tory, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central ha
s elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:220)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resol
veProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAr
eResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not res
olve dependencies for project Test:Test:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find
 org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.
org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempte
d until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:198)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure
to find org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.
apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be rea
ttempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepen
dencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:192)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to
 find org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.ap
ache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reatt
empted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Defa
ultArtifactResolver.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtif
acts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepen
dencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to fin
d org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache
.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempt
ed until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newExcepti
on(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtif
act(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownlo
ads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:599)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownl
oads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:518)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Defa
ultArtifactResolver.java:436)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException
```

Please let me know if I should post any other information to help.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
After deleting the existing repository, and rerunning mvn compile.  I still get the error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Test: Could not resolve depe
ndencies for project Test:Test:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact
org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE in central (http://repo.maven
.apache.org/maven2), try downloading from http://www.springsource.com/download/c
ommunity?project=Spring%20Web%20Services -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Can you include your pom?

Comment: You might want to wipe out your local repository and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @tieTYT I am new to Maven, can you please provide me with the command.  This way we are on the same page... and I do it right ;)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional x64

Comment: OK well for me, my local repository is `C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository`  Try deleting the content in there and see if it resolves itself.

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  I am editing the question with the exact message

Comment: Not that it helps much, but I get the same error with your pom.  You might want to try emailing Spring's mailing list or post on their forum.  My guess is they set something up wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at [The Central Repository](http://search.maven.org)

If you do a search for spring-ws you'll see that there is only a pom file available for download for what you precisely specified in your pom.xml.

Looks like you might want to use spring-ws-core like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That worked!  Next time, how do I go about figuring something like this out?

Comment: I just knew from experience. I read your error more carefully after our back and forth and saw the name of the repo it was defaulting too. Then I searched for the library you specified and saw that it said pom only.  Generally you want at least the pom and jar listed if not the javadoc and sources jars as well.  Good luck man.

Comment: Thanks, I see where it lists "jar" under the "Download" column.  I'm slowly getting the hang of Maven :)

Comment: I was also facing the same issue when I was referring version : <version>2.1.4</version>. It worked after changing the version to "2.1.4.RELEASE"

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a more "regular" way to do this: go to your local maven repository, cd to the directory where that dependency is supposed to be and delete all files (you could even delete the whole org/sprimgframework/ws) then relaunch mvn. It will try to reload all missing dependency.

Comment: I deleted org/springframework/ws and I am receiving the same error.

Comment: Looking the pom of that dependency I see that is downloaded from an ext3rnal repository...but I'm not reeally sure 'cause I'm using my phone and is very hard to read. I'm usjng the same dependency on a project so I will let you know how is configured.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  It seems like spring-ws should be fairly commonly used.  I'm sure I'm just making a Maven newbie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Look for your settings.xml file which is what maven uses to find your repositories.  See what repo it's pointing to and examine that repo to make sure the jars you want exist there.

For example

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>smss-group-m2</id>
                <url>http://repo.mycompany.net/nexus/content/groups/smss-group-m2/</url>
                <releases>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
            <repository>
        </repository>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I just downloaded Maven, so it is the default.  After looking in settings.xml, there is nothing in the "profiles" tag.

Comment: do you have any repo listings in there?

Comment: I do not see any.  Based on the compile output, it appears Maven is looking in "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2".  But I do not see where that is specified.

Answer (score -1):

In the settings.xml file make sure you paste same url of nexus or jfrog repo when you login, whatever url appear on top paste that same

ex:https://artifactory.xxxx/artifactory/webapp/#/home