# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, gmaven-plugin

I am trying to compile the code of georchestra 13.09 and it was working fine for some time but now i can't compile the code
I run the next code ./mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dserver=MyServer and the error is the next

The maven version is the next

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 13:31:09-0400)
Maven home: /opt/georchestra/build-tools/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-52-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

when i run ./mvn clean install -e -X -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dserver=MyServer is the next

```
[INFO] ArcSDE module (dummy-api) ......................... SUCCESS [2.602s]
[INFO] GeoNetwork web client module ...................... FAILURE [22.586s]
[INFO] GeoNetwork Web module ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Download form webapp .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Analytics webapp .................................. SKIPPED
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (create-missingpost-treatment) on project geonetwork-client: Execution create-missingpost-treatment of goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute failed: Plugin org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.georchestra:config:jar:13.09 in Maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (create-missingpost-treatment) on project geonetwork-client: Execution create-missingpost-treatment of goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute failed: Plugin org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.georchestra:config:jar:13.09 in Maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution create-missingpost-treatment of goal org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute failed: Plugin org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.georchestra:config:jar:13.09 in Maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.georchestra:config:jar:13.09 in Maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:78)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.georchestra:config:jar:13.09 in Maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:541)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:395)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:207)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.georchestra:config:jar:13.09 in Maven2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:945)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:940)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:695)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:689)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.get(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:445)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:460)
        ... 27 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :geonetwork-client
```

I try fixing whit these post [Maven Failed to Find dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504046/maven-failed-to-find-dependency) and none of the answers worked for me
mi pom.xml file is the next

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.georchestra</groupId>
<artifactId>root</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>14.06-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Root project of the geOrchestra project</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<organization>
<name>geOrchestra</name>
</organization>
<properties>
<gt.version>9.2</gt.version>
<spring.version>2.5.6.SEC01</spring.version>
<security.version>2.0.5.RELEASE</security.version>
<spring.ldap.version>1.3.0.RELEASE</spring.ldap.version>
<server>template</server>
<sub.target>dev</sub.target>
<!-- default when building without a profile specified -->
<confdir>${project.build.directory}/conf</confdir>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<georchestra.version>${project.version}</georchestra.version>
<postTreatmentScript><![CDATA[
def server=project.properties['server']
def subTarget=project.properties['subTarget']
def params = new Parameters(
project: project,
target: server,
subTarget: subTarget,
log: log,
ant: ant
)
params.init(false)

new PostTreatment().run(this, log, ant, project.basedir, params.projectDir, server, subTarget, project.build.directory)
]]></postTreatmentScript>
</properties>
<modules>
<module>geotools</module>
<module>config</module>
<module>header</module>
<module>epsg-extension</module>
<module>ogc-server-statistics</module>
<module>server-deploy-support</module>
</modules>
<build>
<plugins>
<!-- initialize git revision info -->
<plugin>
<groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.4</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>revision</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<prefix>build</prefix>
<failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
<skipPoms>false</skipPoms>
<verbose>false</verbose>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>create-missingpost-treatment</id>
<phase>prepare-package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>execute</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<source><![CDATA[
def confDir = new File(project.build.directory, "conf")
def treatmentFile = new File(confDir, project.artifactId+"/PostTreatment.groovy")
if(confDir.exists() && !treatmentFile.exists()){
treatmentFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
treatmentFile << """
class PostTreatment {
def run(def project, def log, def ant, def basedirFile, def configDir,
def target, def subTarget, def targetDir) {
log.info("No post treatment required for this project")
}
}
"""
}
]]></source>

</configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
<id>post-treatment-script</id>
<phase>prepare-package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>execute</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<scriptpath>
<element>${project.build.directory}/conf/${project.artifactId}</element>
<element>${project.build.directory}/conf/scripts</element>
</scriptpath>
<source>${postTreatmentScript}</source>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<configuration>
<nonFilteredFileExtensions>
<nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
<nonFilteredFileExtension>swf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
<nonFilteredFileExtension>gif</nonFilteredFileExtension>
<nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
<nonFilteredFileExtension>bmp</nonFilteredFileExtension>
<nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
<nonFilteredFileExtension>odg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
</nonFilteredFileExtensions>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>unpack-config</id>
<goals>
<goal>unpack</goal>
</goals>
<phase>initialize</phase>
<configuration>
<artifactItems>
<artifactItem>
<groupId>org.georchestra</groupId>
<artifactId>config</artifactId>
<version>${georchestra.version}</version>
<classifier>${server}</classifier>
</artifactItem>
</artifactItems>
<overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
<overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
<outputDirectory>${confdir}</outputDirectory>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
<version>6.1.26</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
<configuration>
<classifier>${server}</classifier>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>com.c2c</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
<profiles>

<profile>
<id>localhost</id>
<properties>
<server>localhost</server>
</properties>
</profile>

<!-- template profile -->
<profile>
<id>template</id>
<properties>
<server>template</server>
</properties>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>all</id>
<activation>
<file>
<!-- this is added so that all will be the default profile -->
<!-- one can build only a specific project by doing -->
<!-- -P-all,extractorapp -->
<missing>hack_to_make_all_enabled_by_default</missing>
</file>
</activation>
<modules>
<module>cas-server-webapp</module>
<module>catalogapp</module>
<module>extractorapp</module>
<module>geoserver</module>
<module>ldapadmin</module>
<module>mapfishapp</module>
<module>security-proxy</module>
<module>geonetwork</module>
<module>downloadform</module>
<module>analytics</module>
<module>header</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>cas-server-webapp</id>
<modules>
<module>cas-server-webapp</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>cas</id>
<modules>
<module>cas-server-webapp</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>catalogapp</id>
<modules>
<module>catalogapp</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>header</id>
<modules>
<module>header</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>extractorapp</id>
<modules>
<module>extractorapp</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>geoserver</id>
<modules>
<module>geoserver</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>ldapadmin</id>
<modules>
<module>ldapadmin</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>mapfishapp</id>
<modules>
<module>mapfishapp</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>security-proxy</id>
<modules>
<module>security-proxy</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>proxy</id>
<modules>
<module>security-proxy</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>geonetwork</id>
<modules>
<module>geonetwork</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>downloadform</id>
<modules>
<module>downloadform</module>
</modules>
</profile>

<profile>
<id>analytics</id>
<modules>
<module>analytics</module>
</modules>
</profile>

</profiles>
<repositories>
<repository>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
</snapshots>
<id>mapfish</id>
<url>http://dev.mapfish.org/maven/repository</url>
</repository>
<!-- geotools -->
<repository>
<snapshots>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</snapshots>
<id>osgeo</id>
<name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
<url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>opengeo</id>
<name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
<url>http://repo.opengeo.org/</url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</snapshots>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>jetty-repository</id>
<name>Jetty Maven2 Repository</name>
<url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/jetty/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
<id>codehaus-snapshot-plugins</id>
<name>codehaus-shapshot-plugins</name>
<url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/</url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
<releases>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</releases>
</pluginRepository>
<pluginRepository>
<id>opengeo</id>
<name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
<url>http://repo.opengeo.org/</url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
</pluginRepository>
<pluginRepository>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
</snapshots>
<id>mapfish</id>
<url>http://dev.mapfish.org/maven/repository</url>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Thanks For the Help

Answer (score 0):

That version of GMaven is truely ancient.  I'd try with a newer version or GMavenPlus.