# Maven failure Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to make a Maven project in Eclipse. I get the following failure.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.10 from
>   **"repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"** was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.10 from/to
>   central (**"repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"**): null to
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.10/maven-surefire-plugin-2.10.pom    pom.xml /bookQuote  line
>   1 Maven Configuration Problem

Is there anyone who can help me with this.

I filtered out the hyperlinks, because stackoverflow doesn't allow me to have more than two links. I changed them to the bold style and deleted https://

Comment: If you're using m2e you can try forcing an update of all Maven resources, or, you can locate the local `.m2` repository (usually under your user home directory) and try clearing it out (i.e. deleting the contents) before you do a Maven update. Looks like there are some file conflicts.

Comment: Look at this

: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504046/maven-failed-to-find-dependency

Answer (score 0):

I had similar Issues in the past, simple solution is to delete the existing local repository winthin your .m2 folder and run maven>update project again.

Comment: Let me know if the solution worked or we can look into this further.